# TCL C API Create and Register new Channel

Tags: c++, c, tcl, ofstream, channel

I use Tcl 8.6(windows) and i can't register and use new channels

```
std::ofstream file("1.txt");

Tcl_Channel kanal = Tcl_CreateChannel(Type, "myChann", file, TCL_WRITABLE);
Tcl_RegisterChannel(interp, kanal);

file.close();
```

and the Type is

```
Tcl_ChannelType* Type = new Tcl_ChannelType();
Type->closeProc = closeProc;
Type->inputProc = inputProc;
Type->outputProc = outputProc;
Type->typeName = "My own chann";
Type->version = TCL_CHANNEL_VERSION_2;
```

functions are simply, they have only std::cout

i run interpreter with script

```
"chan puts myChan whatever"
```

and nothing happend, no errors from interpreter, no output(console, file).
i dont know how to bite this,
this is first goal, create new chanel and use it,
the second is to replace TCL_STDOUT with my own channel(it can be std::ofstream),
so that when i run interpreter with

```
"puts WhatEver"
```

that string go to the std::ofstream

Answer (score 0):

Probably you did not flush the output.

This can be done with

```
flush myChan
```

You can also configure your channel to flush at the end of line or whenever anything is written to it:

```
chan configure myChan -buffering line
```

(or `none`). stdout is by default configured with `-buffering line`

Comment: when i 
    "chan flush myChann"
i get infinity loop which run outputProc from Tcl_ChannelType*, when i
     return 0.

and nothing happend when i return 
    int toWrite

Comment: progress, my func was colled, but file still is empty.
how can i get this std::ostream ?

Comment: @user You do need to implement the outputProc correctly, returning the number of bytes actually written. If you always return 0, the flush code will just try again. :-)

Comment: how can i get the correct std::ostream ?
becouse when i create Channel i choose in ClientData std::ofstream,
can i get that std::ostream in outputProc ?
maby from ClientData, but i cant...

Comment: cast it to std::ostream.

Comment: only way to cast this wothout compiler error is 
reinterpret_cast<std::ostream&>
but then i get Access violation reading location error from memory